# Tag merge / synonym request: [regex] -> [regular-expressions]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

[regular-expressions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions) and [regex](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex).

These are the same thing, just one is shorter to type.

Regular-expressions should be the 'master' tag while regex is the synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask and sometimes ye shall receive. In this case, ye has been received. Carry on.